# I can't find my user password or change it

Tags: command-line, password, sudo

In the terminal, whenever I try to perform sudo, Ubuntu asks my password and it always says I typed it in wrong.

I tried changing the password as root, but then it says `password unchanged`.

My user don't have to enter its password on the login screen, and I think that may have something to do with it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Boot in recovery mode as root

perform these commands:

- `mount -o rw,remount /`
- `nano /etc/sudoers`

Look for a line containing `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, below that add this line:

`your_username_here ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

(change your_username_here to your actual username)

(Press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> to exit nano, and answer 'y' to save the changes)

- Enter `passwd your_username_here` and set a new password.

(change your_username_here to your actual username)

- Reboot

([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128213/admin-password-authenticates-to-log-in-but-not-to-install-apps-or-change-user-a))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the right password, double check your caps-lock and num-lock keys.  Those can mess up your password.

Comment: I have no caps lock on or num lock, but I did make it so my user doesn't have to enter their password and I think that may have something to do with it.

Comment: @Paindeer this information is important, I have suggested an edit to include it