# Unable to mount home-directory for user after fresh install 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, users, home-directory

I performed an fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I have /home on a different partition from root. Installing 14.04 and mounting /home went without any problem. During installation I was asked to make a user and I made a new user with my user-name and password. My home folder was correctly added to my user-name. After this I made users for my different family members and adding their existing home folder which went fine except for one.
In one case I could make the new user, same user-name as the home folder. Login for this user failed. The screen turns black and one would expect the desktop for this user to appear. I can hear the drum-sound which indicates that you are logged in, but the login-screen returns. I am unable to login for this one user.
If I try to login this user in cli everything is fine. I can browse the home folder and files.
Of course I don't want to loose the home folder for this user. What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that the user that you are having problems with has a different UID than before.

Answer (score 1):

Elder Geek is right about the UID.

The steps to check the problem goes like this:

```
$ cd /home/[user-name]
$ ls -la
```

You might see the UID is appeared as number rather than your current user name, e.g. appear as 1002

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 (1002) ...bla bla... 40 Mei  22  2014 Documents
```

You can check your current user UID

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep [user-name]
[user-name]:x:1000:1000:[user-name] ...bla bla bla
```

If they are different (1002!=1000) than we know this is the problem.

Solution:

```
$ chmod -R [user-name]:[group-name] /home/[user-name]
```

You may now try to login.

Cheers : )

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem afer installing caffeine. /home/username directory was not present. I created directory and could log in.