# Login issue after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: login

I have a user account that has no password, but Ubuntu wants one after the screen times out and it goes back to the login screen. It won't let you log back in unless you switch users to get back to the regular login scree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454576/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade)

Comment: not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

A user account that has no password? Sounds like a very weird idea to me.

But if that is so then there is absolutely no reason to lock your screen when the screen saver kicks in.

Go to *Settings*/*Brightness and Lock* and disable *Lock*. In this way the screensaver will start but you will not be asked for a password.

[image: screenshot]