# GUI login problems in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm

my problem is very similar to that presented here:
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/553812#553812)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I can enter my account in GUI just for 1-2 seconds after that I am returned
back to the login page.

The origin of troubles started when I was able to enter my account, 
but only the mouse and the background worked there. It was nothing new for 
me, it happened a few times in past, but after reboot everything worked fine.
So I rebooted the system also in this case. 
However, after 3 reboots nothing has been changed so I started to read this forum. 
After attempts to follow solutions recommended there, I get this new 
problem. So now I am still able to enter TTY, but not GUI.

I tried to solve it according to solutions presented on the above mentioned
link, however none of them helped yet. 
I also tried suggestions here:
[Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454576/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade)
despite the fact that my problem is not a consequence of any upgrading.

A few symptoms that can help you to understand my problem:

`.xsession-errors` contains the following message: `Can't open ~/.xinputrc`

The most voted answer from the first link crashes on this line:

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

returns me:

```
dpkg unrecoverable fatal error aborting for package libnfnetlink0:amd64
```

I think, this can be an essential clue. 
I was also trying to solve this problem, but unsuccessfully.

btw. I have created new users to see what happens to them. 
In all the cases all the users face the same problem, after 1-2 seconds 
the login page returns back.

When I enter as a guest user, then the situation is different, 
I can stay in GUI mode, but just the background and the mouse work, nothing else.

I am starting to be very confused, so any idea, any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.