# Cannot login after routine update

Tags: login-screen

I went through a regular daily update a couple of weeks ago, and since then I have been unable to log in to my ubuntu account or the guest account. I have tried the solutions suggested in these threads and none of them have resolved the issue. I would appreciate any suggestions (preferably with some detail--I'm a novice and this is a bit more complicated than anything I've dealt with so far). As far as I can tell, all of my permissions are set correctly, and from the threads I linked to I've figured out that this must be related to the graphics, but I'm out of ideas.

[Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454576/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade) (the description of the problem here is exactly what I'm experiencing)

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Thanks!