# Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 (once again)

Tags: login

I apologize in advance for my naive question but I'm new to Linux and eager to learn. I am experiencing the same problem already commented by others, and it is the impossibility to log-in Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade. After entering the password, I am redirected to the log-in page again.
I followed the instructions appeared in this thread but was unable to solve the issue: [Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454576/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04-after-upgrade)
It seems that I need to edit the system file /etc/fstab but once having accessed to the terminal from the log-in page and cd to the proper directory, I don't know how to edit this file. 
Your valuable feedback is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new myself but lets see if I can help you. Editing fstab could stop your filesystem working so be very careful and back it up first.

Open a terminal

Navigate to the /etc directory
   **cd /etc**

Check you are in the correct directory and fstab is there
   **ls**

Back it up
**sudo cp fstab fstab_old**

Check fstab_old was created
**ls**

Open fstab in a text editor
**sudo gedit fstab**

Make the changes you require in the editor then click the save icon